# Tags used as meta tags: how to resolve?

Tags: discussion, tag

I want to highlight a recurring problem in tagging, where questions are tagged according to the "flavour" of answer they seek, and not according to the question's contents:

**Example 1**:

- *Good*: Questions tagged [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) which are about sharia:

  - [Legal system - does sharia command courts of appeal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36671)
  - [Is Sharia Law only applicable to an Islamic state?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24303)
- *Problematic*: Questions tagged [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) which aren't actually about sharia:

  - [Does nudity invalidate marriage?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37984)
  - [Can a man have up to four wives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38001)

**Example 2**:

- *Good*: Questions tagged [shiism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiism) which are about Shia Islam:

  - [Is familism part of Shia Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38033)
  - [What is the correct definition for "Shia"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29967)
- *Problematic*: Questions tagged [shiism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiism) which aren't actually about Shia Islam:

  - [Is wearing shorts and leggings under for soccer Haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30644)
  - [Is it acceptable to do Wudu in the bathroom? (Shia view)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28060)

In both of these cases, a perfectly good tag is being (mis)used as a meta tag:

> **The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question.** They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.). -- Aaronut, quoted by Jeff Atwood, [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), StackExchange Blog, 2010 (see also [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283907/are-meta-tags-banned-across-the-board-on-all-stack-exchange-sites-or-can-each-si))

*Question*: How can we resolve this?